# Java FX. setCellValueFactory() with using Pair

Tags: java, javafx

I'm struggling with writing setCellValueFactory() for Table column.

**HRSearchController.java**

```
import java.util.List;

import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.util.Pair;

public class HRSearchController {
    private class AreaCell extends ListCell<Area> {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Area a, boolean flag) {
            super.updateItem(a, flag);
            this.setText(a == null ? "" : a.getPostal());
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private TextField input;

    @FXML
    private ListView<Area> list;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Pair<String, String>> table;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Pair<String, String>, String> key;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Pair<String, String>, String> value;

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        list.setCellFactory(lv -> new AreaCell());
        list.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((ob, oldSel, newSel) -> {
            });
    }

    @FXML
    void searchArea(ActionEvent event) {
        String key = input.getText();
        if (!key.isBlank()) {
            ObservableList<Area> model = list.getItems();
            Response result = HRjson.search(key);
            List<Area> location = result.getLocation();
            if (location != null) {
                model.clear();
                model.addAll(location);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

and **Area.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.util.Pair;

public class Area {
    private String prefecture;
    private String city;
    private String town;
    private String city_kana;
    private String town_kana;
    private String x;
    private String y;
    private String postal;

    public String getPrefecture() {
        return prefecture;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public String getTown() {
        return town;
    }

    public String getCity_kana() {
        return city_kana;
    }

    public String getTown_kana() {
        return town_kana;
    }

    public String getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public String getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public String getPostal() {
        return postal;
    }

    List<Pair<String, String>> getPairs() {
        List<Pair<String, String>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
        pairs.add(new Pair<String, String>("郵便番号", postal));
        pairs.add(new Pair<String, String>("都道府県名", prefecture));
        pairs.add(new Pair<String, String>("市区名", city));
        pairs.add(new Pair<String, String>("市区名カナ", city_kana));
        pairs.add(new Pair<String, String>("町村名", town));
        pairs.add(new Pair<String, String>("町村名カナ", town_kana));
        pairs.add(new Pair<String, String>("経度", x));
        pairs.add(new Pair<String, String>("緯度", y));
        return pairs;

    };

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return prefecture + "　" + city + "  (" + city_kana + ") " + town + "  (" + town_kana + ") " + "x: " + x + " "
                + "y: " + y + " " + "〒 " + postal + "\n";
    }

}
```

I want to make results showing vertically in key and value Columns.
Can anybody help me How can I write setCellValueFactory for TableColumn in **HRSearchController** class and then showing results in TableView ?

Usually I used PropertyValueFactory to sets value but with Pair case, I have no idea what to do.

Thank you for your Time.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the value in observable property and set it to cell value factory.

```
TableView<Pair<String,String>> tableView = new TableView<>();
tableView.getItems().addAll(new Pair<>("A","Apple"),new Pair<>("B","Ball"),new Pair<>("C","Cat"));

TableColumn<Pair<String,String>, String> keyCol = new TableColumn<>("Key");
keyCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().getKey()));

TableColumn<Pair<String,String>, String> valCol = new TableColumn<>("Value");
valCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().getValue()));

tableView.getColumns().addAll(keyCol,valCol);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked!!!

Could you explain me what SimpleStringProperty() is doing?

Comment: SimpleStringProperty is an observable property. Cell value factory accepts observable properties ,so that if any change in the observable property will immediately reflect in cell. As `Pair` does'nt have any observable properties, we wrap the value with SimpleStringProperty and provide to cell value factory.